# Avoiding Select 1+n problems

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to list all projects on a page. For each project I want to list all tags for given project. What are my options for speeding this up. The naive implementation generates 1+n select queries.

Can I with a projection force linq-to-sql to fetch all data in one query?

Should I split it up and make a query for projects and one query for tags and put in a dictionary and lookup in my view?(seems like a hack)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use LoadOptions feature:

```
    MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();
    DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();
    options.LoadWith<Project>(p => p.Tags);
    db.LoadOptions = options;
```

After that each query loading Project entity will download Tags as well.